# Is available set access permissions only for my user for sshfs mountpoint

Tags: ssh, sshfs

I create in `/media/$USER` new directory `myvps`. Set permissions 700.

Next I mount remote directory by `sshfs`.

Now my vps directory has `root:root` owner. Of couse, I can not get access from my `$USER`.

So, is available get access to directory `myvps` after mount remote directory only for my user?

Comment: Maybe you want to use something like that: `sshfs -o uid=xxxx -o gid=yyyy [user@]host:[dir] mountpoint [options]`

Answer (score 0):

Use options `uid` and `gid`:

> -o uid=N set file owner
>
> -o gid=N set file group

More information [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs).

Code from my bash-script:

```
sshfs $VPS:$MPATH $TARGET_PATH -o reconnect -o follow_symlinks -o IdentityFile=$VPS_KEY -oauto_cache,reconnect,default_permissions,uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g $USER)
```

*PS: thanks @tobiasBora*

Comment: For other reviewers, while this looks like a “thank you” answer, it’s really a transcription of an answer given in a comment.

Comment: Yura, please write this up a bit more formally as an answer, standing on its own (without reference to the comment).